# How can i save and load a model in tensorflow (no keras)

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, model, training-data

Suppose we have a model like this that we want to train

```
X = tf.placeholder("float32", shape=[None, input_size])  
y = tf.placeholder("int32", shape=[None])
w_1 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([X.shape[1],hid_size]))   
b_1 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([hid_size]))

w_2 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([hid_size,output_size]))
b_2 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([output_size]))

h = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(X, w_1) + b_1)
output=tf.add(tf.matmul(h,w_2),b_2)

loss_func=tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=output,labels=y)
loss=tf.reduce_sum(loss_func)
optimizer=tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate)
train_op=optimizer.minimize(loss)
```

Is there any way we can somehow save that model after the training so we don't have to train it all over again?